# What is difference between .collectAsList() and .toLocalIterator() in Spark Scala

Tags: apache-spark, dataset

I have a Spark Dataset and it can be small or up to more than 500k rows.

I need to collect as List in Java.
I came across methods as `collectAsList()` and `toLocalIterator()`. What is the difference between these two. 
Once the collect as list is done . I wouldn't need this dataset.

Comment: in short, `collectAsList` sends all data to the driver immediately, `toLocalIterator` sends partition-wise data to the driver. If you need all the data and you cannot condens them on the driver, `toLocalIterator` has no advantage

Comment: Thanks for the explanation